# Can you use multiple "logical and" and "logical or" in an if condition?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a method only take action if the char value of the unicode character is a number, uppercase alphabet, or lowercase alphabet.

```
if ((48<=msg[i]&&msg[i]>=57)||(65<=msg[i]&&msg[i]>=90)||(97<=msg[i]&&msg[i]>=122) // only if numeral or alphabet   
{
      System.out.print("PASS");
}
```

(I have changed the action to displaying "PASS" just for sake of simplification.)
This is not working as I have input a ? character and it got a "PASS".
I seem to have an incorrect understanding of how to use these operators. 
How am I wrong? How do I achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: It would be clearer if you use '0' and '9' etc instead of 48 and 57

Answer (score 5):

Invert your relational operators. `>=` to `<=` in the second conditions.

```
if ((48<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=57)||(65<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=90)||(97<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=122)
```

`(48<=msg[i]&&msg[i]>=57)` will mean "PASS" if `msg[i]` is `>=` 48 and `>=` 57 i.e. if it is just `>=` 57.

**OR**

If you don't want to check for ASCII codes, try using.

`isLetterOrDigit()` of `Character` class.

**OR**

Use Regex.

```
if((""+msg[i]).matches("^[A-Za-z0-9]$"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong comparison operator at the second operand in each of the `&&` operators.

It should be :

```
if ((48<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=57)||(65<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=90)||(97<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<=122) // only if numeral or alphabet   
{
    System.out.print("PASS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply avoid ASCII values cause its more confusing. Try following code:

```
if (('0'<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<='9')||('A'<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<='Z')||('a'<=msg[i]&&msg[i]<='z') // only if numeral or alphabet   
{
System.out.print("PASS");
}
```